# How to read this LeakCanary Log?what does it mean in detail?

Tags: leakcanary

Is it possible to specify in detail which code specifically represents what does this mean?

I known DownLoadActivity has leaked,but I don't known where,Is it possible to specify in detail which code specifically represents what does this mean?

```
* com.combanc.activityv2.DownLoadActivity has leaked:
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: * GC ROOT thread java.lang.Thread.<Java Local> (named 'pool-3-thread-2')
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: * leaks com.combanc.activityv2.DownLoadActivity instance
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: * Retaining: 112 KB.
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: * Reference Key: 952bf634-0b9c-464a-9ac5-1f3c9a96c334
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: * Device: LENOVO Lenovo YOGA Tablet 2-1050F YT2_10_prc_wifi
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: * Android Version: 4.4.2 API: 19 LeakCanary: 1.5 00f37f5
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: * Durations: watch=5024ms, gc=130ms, heap dump=381ms, analysis=11764ms
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: * Details:
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: * Instance of java.lang.Thread
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   static $staticOverhead = byte[144]@1130742801 (0x4365c411)
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   static NORM_PRIORITY = 5
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   static defaultUncaughtHandler = u.aly.as@1139270480 (0x43e7e350)
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   static count = 503
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   static MIN_PRIORITY = 1
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   static NANOS_PER_MILLI = 1000000
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   static MAX_PRIORITY = 10
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   contextClassLoader = dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@1138919248 (0x43e28750)
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   vmThread = java.lang.VMThread@1178237536 (0x463a7a60)
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   group = java.lang.ThreadGroup@1130803552 (0x4366b160)
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   uncaughtHandler = null
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   target = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker@1178079776 (0x46381220)
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   inheritableValues = null
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   interruptActions = java.util.ArrayList@1178237632 (0x463a7ac0)
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   localValues = null
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   name = java.lang.String@1178237664 (0x463a7ae0)
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   parkBlocker = java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferStack@1139020592 (0x43e41330)
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   id = 501
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   stackSize = 0
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   priority = 5
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   parkState = 3
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   hasBeenStarted = true
03-09 17:11:44.319 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   daemon = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: * Instance of com.combanc.activityv2.DownLoadActivity
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   zipResourcesPath = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   speedTv = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   resourcesExistedTv = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   progressBar1 = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mSubjectUrl = java.lang.String@1139649168 (0x43edaa90)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mSubjectFileName = java.lang.String@1171271136 (0x45d02de0)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   deleteBtn = android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton@1171245344 (0x45cfc920)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   detailTv = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   downloadListener = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   filenameTv = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mLoginAnimationView = com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView@1170312112 (0x45c18bb0)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mSharedPreferences = android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl@1138934816 (0x43e2c420)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   SKIP = 8
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   PARSE_STUDENT_INFO = 5
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   PARSE_PREPARE_SUBJECT = 6
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   PARSE_GROUP_INFO = 7
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS = 4
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   DOWNLOAD_FAILED = 3
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mDelegate = android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14@1170203120 (0x45bfe1f0)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mResources = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mEatKeyUpEvent = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mThemeId = 2131296541
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mPendingFragmentActivityResults = android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat@1170206128 (0x45bfedb0)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mFragments = android.support.v4.app.FragmentController@1170199792 (0x45bfd4f0)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mHandler = android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity$1@1170199536 (0x45bfd3f0)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mNextCandidateRequestIndex = 0
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mOptionsMenuInvalidated = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mCreated = true
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mReallyStopped = true
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mRequestedPermissionsFromFragment = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mResumed = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mRetaining = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mStopped = true
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mStartedActivityFromFragment = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mStartedIntentSenderFromFragment = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mExtraDataMap = android.support.v4.util.SimpleArrayMap@1170199504 (0x45bfd3d0)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mActionBar = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mActivityInfo = android.content.pm.ActivityInfo@1170196736 (0x45bfc900)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mAllLoaderManagers = android.util.ArrayMap@1171306336 (0x45d0b760)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mApplication = com.combanc.util.BaseApplication@1138924928 (0x43e29d80)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mBlur = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mWindowManager = android.view.WindowManagerImpl@1170202928 (0x45bfe130)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mWindow = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow@1170200960 (0x45bfd980)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mUiThread = java.lang.Thread@1130808160 (0x4366c360)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mTranslucentCallback = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mComponent = android.content.ComponentName@1142166112 (0x44141260)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mToken = android.os.BinderProxy@1142166048 (0x44141220)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mContainer = android.app.Activity$1@1170199328 (0x45bfd320)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mCurrentConfig = android.content.res.Configuration@1170200736 (0x45bfd8a0)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mDecor = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mTitle = java.lang.String@1141185504 (0x44051be0)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mDefaultKeySsb = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mSearchManager = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mResultData = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mEmbeddedID = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mParent = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mMenuInflater = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mFragments = android.app.FragmentManagerImpl@1170199200 (0x45bfd2a0)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mHandler = android.os.Handler@1170199472 (0x45bfd3b0)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mManagedDialogs = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mInstanceTracker = android.os.StrictMode$InstanceTracker@1170199376 (0x45bfd350)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mInstrumentation = android.app.Instrumentation@1138919040 (0x43e28680)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mIntent = android.content.Intent@1142167360 (0x44141740)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mLastNonConfigurationInstances = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mLoaderManager = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mManagedCursors = java.util.ArrayList@1170199344 (0x45bfd330)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mMainThread = android.app.ActivityThread@1138837456 (0x43e147d0)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mLoadersStarted = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mIdent = 573043384
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mFinished = true
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mEnableDefaultActionBarUp = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mResultCode = 0
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mDoReportFullyDrawn = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mResumed = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mDestroyed = true
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mStartedActivity = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mStopped = true
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mTemporaryPause = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mDefaultKeyMode = 0
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mTitleColor = 0
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mTitleReady = true
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mConfigChangeFlags = 0
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mCheckedForLoaderManager = true
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mChangingConfigurations = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mVisibleFromClient = true
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mVisibleFromServer = true
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mChangeCanvasToTranslucent = false
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mWindowAdded = true
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mCalled = true
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl@1170199808 (0x45bfd500)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mInflater = com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater@1170202432 (0x45bfdf40)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mOverrideConfiguration = null
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mResources = android.content.res.Resources@1138915376 (0x43e27830)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mTheme = android.content.res.Resources$Theme@1170202960 (0x45bfe150)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mThemeResource = 2131296541
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mBase = android.app.ContextImpl@1170199808 (0x45bfd500)
03-09 17:11:44.329 5358-5980/com.combanc.activityv2 D/LeakCanary: |   mRomUIVersion = 0
```

Comment: Kindly add in proper file format.

Comment: @ keyur9779  sorry, I changed it，It is right now?

Comment: Its detail of DownLoadActivity class.
In which it show memory used by class is 112kb,
details of class object like button , fragment etc.